# Is it possible to control Jasper Reports field usage in page footer?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to add a text field with a simple expression:

```
$F{foo}
```

to the page footer band. However, it seems no matter what evaluation time I choose, it always shows value of field `foo` from the very first row. Is it possible to make it show value from the *last* row?

Comment: last row of the page or the last row of report(A report with multiple pages) ?

Comment: @cjava: Last row of the report, regardless of pages.

Comment: @doublep What version of *JR* did you use? It's works fine for me (4.8.0)

Comment: @AlexK: Oh, that might be it. AFAIR we use a very old (3.5? cannot check now) version on production; in current development we have 5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="show_last_row_in_footer" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="106e6d12-70ca-44b4-a55d-845952f57346">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <sortField name="name"/>
    <variable name="firstValueOnPage" class="java.lang.String" resetType="Page" calculation="First">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="5f3d2dfa-b44c-43eb-ac49-aa4ebb81b733" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="5f3d2dfa-b44c-43eb-ac49-aa4ebb81b733" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="55abd358-2770-4337-a117-3f8592ce0a34" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="50"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="55abd358-2770-4337-a117-3f8592ce0a34" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="43" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField evaluationTime="Page">
                <reportElement uuid="e147d45b-45a3-4749-829f-b648a2c7805f" x="0" y="0" width="163" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["The last id on page: " + $F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="bbf6f99a-c60c-42e9-8147-97b9f3ee4316" x="326" y="0" width="138" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["The first id on page: " + $V{firstValueOnPage}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement uuid="e147d45b-45a3-4749-829f-b648a2c7805f" x="163" y="0" width="163" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["The last id for report: " + $F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="9ecd61c0-98fa-4282-a0d1-cd8cd325f987" x="435" y="23" width="80" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement uuid="1c663c4d-1279-447a-91d6-6d03bc53a841" x="515" y="23" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

I have tested sample with this *CSV datasource*:

```
Oslo,45
Berne,22
Boston,32
Chicago,39
Chicago,35
New York,44
Chicago,11
Dallas,47
Oslo,42
Dallas,43
Paris,5
San Francisco,48
Paris,18
Dallas,4
Boston,23
Dallas,0
Dallas,19
Dallas,10
Lyon,38
Lyon,2
Dallas,40
Dallas,36
Dallas,37
Lyon,28
Lyon,17
New York,46
New York,41
Paris,25
San Francisco,7
Berne,9
```

The first page of resulted report will be (built in *iReport v 4.8.0*):

[image: The first page of report generated via iReport]

The last page of the resulted report will be (built in *iReport v 4.8.0*):

[image]

For getting *last row on page* value (blue color) I've used expression with default *evaluationTime* or *evaluationTime* equals **Page** value.

For getting *first row on page* value (red color) I've used variable (*firstValueOnPage*) with this  attributes: 
*resetType*: **Page** 
*calculation*: **First**

For showing the *last row of the whole report* (green color) value I've used *evaluationTime* equals **Report** value.

---

I have used *iReport 4.8.0*.

I've added sorting by *name* field. You will get the same behavior for data without sorting.